# What event should I use to submit a form asynchronously in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently started using jQuery/AJAX for submitting data to my PHP API.

Currently what I'm using is an input type="button" in the html and then a .click() jQuery function to submit it.

I'm not quite sure it's the best way to do it though, should I use a input type="submit" with preventDefault() instead ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to use `.submit()` on the form instead of `.click()` on the submit button. In both cases `preventDefault` is necessary though. The reason for that is that the user could submit the form by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while editing some field and if you subscribed to the .click event of a button, this event won't fire.

Comment: An alternative to preventDefault is `return false;`. Upvoting anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.submit()`, you just have to insert `return false;` in your callback to prevent actual form submission and do your own operations.

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Or like @DarinDimitrov says, by using `preventDefault`.

Comment: From JQuery's docs: "Depending on the browser, the Enter key may only cause a form submission if the form has exactly one text field, or only when there is a submit button present. The interface should not rely on a particular behavior for this key unless the issue is forced by observing the keypress event for presses of the Enter key."

Answer (score 1):

Submitting is not limited to any specific events via jquery. You can use any event which exists like click or customized methods/functions written by you or other to send the ajax request depending on user behavior like hover or any other. 
Simply how you use jquery ajax is limited by your imagination and practice.